# Find files with at least one CR LF

Tags: linux, bash, newline

I am on Linux. I have received a mixed list of files, which I have forgotten to verify beforehand. My editor (emacs) has used LF (`\n`) for some files which originally had CR+LF (`\r\n`) (!!). I have realized about this way too late, and I think this is causing me trouble.

I would like to find all files in my cwd which have **at least** one CR+LF in them. I do not trust the `file` command, because I think it only checks the first lines, and not the whole file.

I would like **to check whole files to look for CR + LF**. Is there a tool for that, or do I need to roll my own?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this `grep` command to list all the files in a directory with at least one `CR-LF`:

```
grep -l $'\r$' *
```

Pattern `$'\r$'` will file `\r` just before end of each line.

Or using hex value:

```
grep -l $'\x0D$' *
```

Where `\x0D` will find `\r` (ASCII: 13).

Comment: ehhh? What is that `$` doing before the pattern? Can you clarify?

Comment: I don't think that this works in some environments, e.g. when using the version of `grep` which comes with Git Bash on Windows. It should work on an environment that expects newlines to be `\n` though.

Comment: Right but OP is on Linux (as per tag).

Comment: This is giving me a lot of false positives on linux (bash shell). A lot means here "all files are marked as having CR+LF", which is most certainly incorrect.

Comment: @jeckyll2hide: `$'..'` is called **escaped sequence**. The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.

Comment: I've tested it myself and it is finding only a file that has `CR-LF` line ending.

Comment: Yep, right, I was doing grep -r and it was finding lots of binary files (my mistake)

Comment: _grep which comes with Git Bash on Windows_ Yes, it ist'n work with git bash, but work in WSL.

Answer (score 0):

dos2unix can not only convert dos line ends (CR+LF) to unis (LF) but also display file information with a -i option. e.g.

```
sh-4.3$ (echo "1" ; echo "") > 123.txt 
sh-4.3$ unix2dos 123.txt 
unix2dos: converting file 123.txt to DOS format...
sh-4.3$ cat 123.txt ; hexdump -C 123.txt ; dos2unix --info='du' 123.txt
1

00000000  31 0d 0a 0d 0a                                    |1....|
00000005
       2       0  123.txt
sh-4.3$ dos2unix 123.txt 
dos2unix: converting file 123.txt to Unix format...
sh-4.3$ cat 123.txt ; hexdump -C 123.txt ; dos2unix --info='du' 123.txt
1

00000000  31 0a 0a                                          |1..|
00000003
       0       2  123.txt
```

Comment: It is even simpler when you use the 'c' flag. To list all files with DOS line breaks:

dos2unix -ic *

List all files with Unix line breaks:

unix2dos -ic *